# merging multiple tables - pd.concat: append vs yield

Tags: python, pandas

Assume we have quite a few of `.xls` or `.xlsx` files stored in a directory, and there are two ways of feeding them into `pd.concat` to get one big table: yield vs append.

```py
def append_method(path):
    container = []
    for f in path.rglob("*.xls*"):
        df = pd.read_excel(f)
        container.append(df)
    return container


def yield_method(path):
    for f in path.rglob("*.xls*"):
        df = pd.read_excel(f)
        yield df

        
path = Path("...")
        
## append
data = append_method(path)
tables = pd.concat(data)

## yield 
data = yield_method(path)
tables = pd.concat(data)
```

---

Judging by `%%timeit` magic, both are pretty much the same?

*tested on 100 xls/xlsx files*

```
append: 11.8 s ± 667 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
 yield: 12.7 s ± 1.03 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

If there's a difference between these two, which one should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pandas docs note that:

> It is worth noting that concat() (and therefore append()) makes a full
> copy of the data, and that constantly reusing this function can create
> a significant performance hit. If you need to use the operation over
> several datasets, use a list comprehension.  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html

Based on your timing results, it looks like `read_excel()` is the slowest part.

UPDATE:
I would use the yield method.

- the function `yield_method()`returns a generator, which is empty after invoking `pd.concat()`.  It doesn't take space/resources, and communicates the intention that it has served its purpose.
- the `append_method()` returns a list of data frames, which will continue to consume space from the call to pd.concat() until the garbage collector runs.

Comment: I see, thank you. That's what I thought regarding the yield method, but I only considered time it takes to concat files. That's interesting!